# Issue in namenode, exception type javaBinding

Tags: hadoop

I don't know exactly the source of probleme when i start hadoop namenode. exception say we have problem type javaBinding exception but when i verefy the port with netstat i don't find the port listned by any processus anyone can help me please and thank you in  advance

Comment: Please provide your error message

Comment: 19/08/02 14:03:18 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:50020] java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException

Comment: this is my probleme, i changed the default port of namenode and datanode, for namenode work well but for datanode i have the upper problem

Comment: @user2738882 , if you have any idea about this share it with and thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see the following link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/BindException

Comment: @user2738882 this link provides when errors generate. i tested ping but always error not solved. thank you